# Is it possible to have overlapping page transitions in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-transition

Say I have an `out:` transition on an element in a SvelteKit route "A" and another `in:` transition on some other element in route "B". Wenn navigating from page A to B, the transition of A has to finish before the elements of page B are shown.

Is there a way to have the elements of page A and B overlap during their transitions?

###### Page A

```html
<script>
    import { fly } from "svelte/transition";
</script>

<header out:fly={{ y: 100 }}>
...
```

###### Page B

```html
...
<header in:fly={{ y: 100 }}>
...
```

###### File structure

```
 project
 └  src
   └  routes 
      ├  route-a.svelte
      └  route-b.svelte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in Svelte 3.48.0 + SvelteKit 1.0.0-next.350, the problem is not *"transition of A has to finish before the elements of page B are shown"*, because SvelteKit starts "Page A" and "Page B" transitions after the "Page B" is loaded. You can see it if you add (uncomment) a delay to the `src/routes/b.js` endpoint in my example below.

The problem is with the fly transition and CSS — "Page A" occupies a space until "Page A" transition is finished. You can solve this by [this workaround](https://imfeld.dev/writing/svelte_overlapping_transitions) (the one used in my example below) or by using another transition (`slide`, for example).

## Worked example with fly transition overlapping

**src/routes/__layout.svelte:**

```
<nav>
    <a href='/a'>Page A</a> | <a href='/b'>Page B</a>
</nav>

<div>
    <slot/>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    div>:global(*) {
        grid-row: 1;
        grid-column: 1;
    }
</style>
```

**src/routes/a.svelte:**

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
</script>

<header out:fly={{ y: 100, duration: 2000 }}>
aaaaaaa
</header>

<style>
    header {
        height: 200px;
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>
```

**src/routes/b.svelte:**

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
    export let text
</script>

<header in:fly={{ y: 100, duration: 2000 }}>
{text}
</header>

<style>
    header {
        height: 200px;
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>
```

**src/routes/b.js:**

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'

export async function get() {
    // await setTimeout(1000)
    return {
        body: {
            text: 'bbbbbbbbb'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a small example, let me know if I should add more. I've had a look at deferred transitions and experimented with them unsuccessfully. My understanding is that they are for transitions between identical elements.

Comment: Are "Page A" and "Page B" pages (routes) in a Single Page Application? Are they located in something like `src/routes/pageA.svelte` and `src/routes/pageB.svelte`?

Comment: Yes it's a SvelteKit SPA and page a/b are routes.

Comment: Try to test my new example